# Navigation Bar Failure

Tags: html

So I have an navigation bar for my website that is pretty basic, you click on the word and it takes you to that page. Well after putting a drop down on my page the navigation menu suddenly stopped working. Can anyone see a problem here that I am missing that would allowing the navigation menu to suddenly stop working after a drop down menu occurs?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #333;
}

li {
    float: left;
}

li a {
    display: block;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

li a:hover:not(.active) {
    background-color: #111;
}

.active {
    background-color: #4CAF50;

    }


.dropdown-notification {
 height: 25vh;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 999;
  line-height: 40px;
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  animation: welcome-dropdown 2s ease, welcome-fadeout 2s 4s forwards;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  line-height: 25vh;
  font-size: 70px;
}

@keyframes welcome-dropdown {
  from {
    transform: translateY(calc(-100vh));
  }
  to {
    transform: translateY(0);
  }
}

@keyframes welcome-fadeout {
  from {
    opacity: 1;
  }

  to {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}  
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="dropdown-notification text-center">
        Welcome to All About History
   </div>



 <nav>
  <ul>
     <li><a class="active" href="website.html">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="about.html">About Me</a></li>
    <li><a href="people.html">People in History</a></li>
    <li><a href="contact.html">Contact Me</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You set the dropdown to have `z-index: 999`, but even without this, the dropdown div is on top of the nav element, it just fades to `opacity: 0` and you can't click through it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This happens because your dropdown has `z-index:999`. Even though it fades out it is still there on top of the navigation bar with 0 opacity. In your `welcome-fadeout`, make the z-index '-1' so that nav bar comes on top of the banner

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #333;
}

li {
    float: left;
}

li a {
    display: block;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

li a:hover:not(.active) {
    background-color: #111;
}

.active {
    background-color: #4CAF50;

    }


.dropdown-notification {
 height: 25vh;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 999;
  line-height: 40px;
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  animation: welcome-dropdown 2s ease, welcome-fadeout 2s 4s forwards;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  line-height: 25vh;
  font-size: 70px;
}

@keyframes welcome-dropdown {
  from {
    transform: translateY(calc(-100vh));
  }
  to {
    transform: translateY(0);
  }
}

@keyframes welcome-fadeout {
  from {
    opacity: 1;
  }

  to {
    opacity: 0;
    z-index: -1;
  }
}  
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="dropdown-notification text-center">
        Welcome to All About History
   </div>



 <nav>
  <ul>
     <li><a class="active" href="website.html">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="about.html">About Me</a></li>
    <li><a href="people.html">People in History</a></li>
    <li><a href="contact.html">Contact Me</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks so much! I can't believe I didn't catch that

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `visibility:hidden` property instead of `z-index:-1`. It also works. It's just a another approach to fix it.

```
to {
opacity: 0;
visibility:hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<body>
<div class="dropdown-notification text-center"> Welcome to All About History </div>
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a class="active" href="website.html">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="about.html">About Me</a></li>
    <li><a href="people.html">People in History</a></li>
    <li><a href="contact.html">Contact Me</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
<style>
ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #333;
}
li {
    float: left;
}
li a {
    display: block;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
}
li a:hover:not(.active) {
    background-color: #111;
}
.active {
    background-color: #4CAF50;
}
.dropdown-notification {
    height: 25vh;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    z-index: 999;
    line-height: 40px;
    background-color: #4CAF50;
    animation: welcome-dropdown 2s ease, welcome-fadeout 2s 4s forwards;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    line-height: 25vh;
    font-size: 70px;
}
@keyframes welcome-dropdown {
    from {
        transform: translateY(calc(-100vh));
    }
    to {
        transform: translateY(0vh);
    }
}
@keyframes welcome-fadeout {
    from {
        opacity: 1;
    }
    to {
        opacity: 0;
        height: 0vh;
    }
}  
</style>
</body>
</html>
```